Stuck on a linear system of DEs by Laplace transform
$x_1''-2x_2'+3x=0$,
$x_2''+2x_1'+3x_2=0$
where $x_1(0)=4,x_1'(0)=0,x_2(0)=0,x_2'(0)=0$
Applied Laplace transform to both equations
$4s=(s^2+3)X_1-2sX_2 ...(1)$
$8=(s^2+3)X_2+2sX_1$
can yall guide me to where to move forward from here, please.

(i) Solve the system of equations in $X_1, X_2$; (ii) compute the inverse Laplace transform of $X_1(s)$ and $X_2(s)$.

Your first equation has an $x$ without a subscript---presumably it should be $x_1$ to match your work.

While not at all necessary, the following observation is too pretty to not make. Namely, these real differential equations may be combined into one complex differential equation:
$$x_1''-2x_2'+3x_1+i(x_2''+2x_1'+3x_2)=(x_1+i x_2)''+2i(x_1+i x_2)'+3(x_1+ix_2)=0$$
So the complex variable $z:=x_1+i x_2$ satisfies the differential equation $z''+2iz'+3z=0$, with initial conditions $z(0)=4$, $z'(0)=0$. We could solve this with the usual $e^{\lambda t}$ ansatz, but I'll stick with the Laplace transform method. This yields the transformed equation as
$$(s^2+2is+3) Z-4s-8i=0$$
which we may solve and rearrange to get
$$Z=\frac{4s+8 i}{s^2+2is+3}=\frac{4(s+2i)}{(s-i)(s+3i)}=\frac{3}{s-i}+\frac{1}{s+3i}$$
Hence we may inverse transform to get $z(t)=3e^{it}+e^{-3it}$, which we may confirm solves the requisite differential equation. Taking real and imaginary parts then obtains the desired results.
